# Adding UL using DOM Manipulation Not Working. Help is appreciated

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Learning About Nodes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Hammerhead</li>
      <li>Tiger</li>
      <li>Great White</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="btn">Just do it</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
btnElement = document.getElementById("#btn");
    if (btnElement) {
      btnElement.addEventlistener("click", justdoitFunction);
    }

    function justdoitFunction() {
      const ul2 = document.createElement("ul");
      document.body.appendChild(ul);
      const listElement = document.createElement("li");
      listElement.textContent = "This is done by Panda.";
      
      ul2.appendChild(listElement);
    }
```

I am trying to add a text content using the just do it button. I don't see what the mistake is. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no element with id of `#btn` in the document, there is an element with the id of `btn`, though.

Comment: On the HTML I have given the button an id of btn

Comment: Yes, but you're retrieving `#btn`, that's not the same. `getElementById` doesn't take a selector, it takes the value of the id.

Comment: Also a type in `addEventlistener` should be `addEventListener`

Comment: @Teemu and aerial301 Thanks Guys. So I found out my mistake was getting the btn selector and the addEventListener misspelling.  Thank now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some syntax errors, so i fixed it here:

```js
const btnElement = document.getElementById("btn");

function justdoitFunction() {
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
  const listElement = document.createElement("li");
  listElement.textContent = "This is done by Panda.";

  ul.appendChild(listElement);
}


if (btnElement) {
  btnElement.addEventListener("click", justdoitFunction);
}
```

But I can see that you are trying to insert an item into a `ul` list. Instead of creating a new whole list each time you click the button, try to select the existing list and add the item there:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Learning About Nodes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="list">
      <li>Hammerhead</li>
      <li>Tiger</li>
      <li>Great White</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="btn">Just do it</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
const btnElement = document.getElementById("btn");

function justdoitFunction() {
  const ul = document.getElementById("list");

  const listElement = document.createElement("li");
  listElement.textContent = "This is done by Panda.";
  ul.appendChild(listElement);
}


if (btnElement) {
  btnElement.addEventListener("click", justdoitFunction);
}
```

Comment: Perfect it works now!